# Cannot install tuxboot - repository does not have a Release file?

Tags: 18.04, ppa

Trying to install `tuxboot` using Ubuntu PPA (Ubuntu 18.04), like so:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot
```

but I get

```
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot/ubuntu bionic Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have read multiple accounts of users that successfully used the PPA to install `tuxboot`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you open the PPA up in a browser, you'll note it does not support releases past [16.04] Xenial (ie. look at http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot/ubuntu/dists/ and you'll note no directories for any release > xenial)

Comment: You should always check package existence in PPA for your release. This PPA [does not have packages for bionic](https://launchpad.net/~thomas.tsai/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-tuxboot). You can contact PPA owner and request packaging for 18.04 LTS (if you are interested).